# Typescript - map one object into another

Tags: typescript

I need help writing a function that maps an object to another object

1. I assume that the output object should be type formed for "build time" by "&" from "InputTypeOne" and "InputTypeTwo" to have all possible fields from "InputTypeOne" and "InputTypeTwo":

"const output: Partial <OutputType <InputTypeOne & InputTypeTwo >> = {};"

Afer adding all needed properties I convert it to the output object:

"return the output as OutputType;"

Not sure if this right approach?

2. I also have problem with conditional types (i have added two comments in code below)

All code below

```
// input object properties types
interface InputTypeText {
  type: 'text'
  value: string;
}

interface InputTypeReference {
  type: 'reference'
  value: InputTypeTwo
}

interface OutputTypeReference {
  testA: string;
}

// input object types
interface InputTypeOne {
  name: InputTypeText;
  references?: InputTypeReference[]
}

interface InputTypeTwo {
  name: InputTypeText;
}

// ouput object types
type OuputType<E extends InputTypeOne | InputTypeTwo> = {
  [K in keyof E]: (
    E[K] extends InputTypeText ? string :
    E[K] extends InputTypeReference[] ? OutputTypeReference[] :
    never
  )
}

const objTypeOne: InputTypeOne | InputTypeTwo = {
  name: {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Some name'
  },
}

const objTypeTwo: InputTypeOne | InputTypeTwo = {
  name: {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'Some name'
  },
  references: [{
    type: 'reference',
    value: objTypeOne
  }]
}


type OnOrTwo = InputTypeOne | InputTypeTwo;
type OnAndTwo = InputTypeOne & InputTypeTwo;

type InputTypeOneOrTwo = InputTypeOne | InputTypeTwo;
type KeyofOneOrTwo = keyof InputTypeOne;

type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type AvailableKeys = KeysOfUnion<OnOrTwo>;
type Values = OnAndTwo[AvailableKeys];


function hasOwnProperty<T extends OnAndTwo, K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: T,
  prop: K
): obj is T & Record<K, Values> {
  return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}

function mapOneTypeToOtherType<T extends OnAndTwo>(entity: T): OuputType<T> {
  const output: Partial<OuputType<OnAndTwo>> = {};
  
  Object.keys(entity).forEach((key) => {
    const keyRef = key as AvailableKeys
    if (hasOwnProperty(entity, keyRef)) {
      // Got Object is possibly 'undefined'. How to write properly hasOwnProperty and/or AvailableKeys to access type property below? 
      if (entity[keyRef].type === 'text') {
        // How to determine that output with this key should be type of string because of  entity[key].type === 'text' and Type of ouput object.  
        output[key] = 'strgin here';
      }
    }

  });

  return output as OuputType<T>;
};
const objTypeOneOuput = mapOneTypeToOtherType(objTypeOne);
const objTypeTwoOuput = mapOneTypeToOtherType(objTypeTwo);

// Ouput object one should have only "name"
objTypeOneOuput.name = 'test';

// Ouput object two should have name an "references"
objTypeTwoOuput.name = 'test'
objTypeTwoOuput.references = [{ testA: 'string' }]
```

Comment: [Please consider asking only one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366); I suggest you choose either 1 or 2 to be the primary question and [edit] to move the other one to its own post.